# Is there a way to hide prices?

Tags: orders

I am planning to allow the guest user to be able to view the product catalog.  But I would like them not to see the prices.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Already been answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299366/hide-prices-and-disable-checkout-for-guests

Comment: check this answer its exactly what you need !
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325934/best-to-call-a-template-within-a-template-magento/12335809#12335809

Comment: We should answer this question once on the magento SO site, to use it as reference. We can only mark duplicates inside our site :-) so please copy the comment into an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a few options:

**Do it yourself**

*app/design/frontend/default/default/template/catalog/product/price.phtml*

insert at the very beggining of the file:

`<?php if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) { ?>`

insert at the very end of the file

`<?php } ?>`

hiding add to cart:

*app/design/frontend/default/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml*

```
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                    <button class="form-button" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></button>
                <?php else: ?>
                <div class="out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></div>
                <?php endif; ?>
```

before that code insert:

`<?php if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) { ?>`

after that code insert:

`<?php } ?>`

you will find two times in the file..(one for the list mode one for grid mode!)

*app/design/frontend/default/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml*

```
<div class="add-to-holder">
                    <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
                        <?php if( $this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow() || $_compareUrl=$this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddUrl($_product)): ?>
                            <span class="add-or"><?php // echo $this->__('OR') ?></span>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
                </div>
```

before that code insert:

`<?php if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) { ?>`

after that code insert:

`<?php } ?>`

if you have tier prices etc.. you have to use the same trick in the other files. u can find them in one of this files in the folder:

*app/design/frontend/default/default/template/catalog/product/*

*Source:* http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/22673/

---

**Install a module**

There are several available:

A free B2B plugin on Github that lists hiding prices for guests among its features:

https://github.com/sitewards/B2BProfessional

Or, one you can buy:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/bolasevich/extension/2096/hide-product-price-for-non-registered-users

Finally, one that is even more expensive:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Cart2Quote/extension/5905/not2order_hide_price_disable_ordering

---

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299366/hide-prices-and-disable-checkout-for-guests