# Hide prices in Magento article

Tags: price

Regarding to the post below, how can I add "Login to View Price" if the user is not signed in? What is the code?

[Is there a way to hide prices?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/537/is-there-a-way-to-hide-prices/36849#36849)

Thank you in advance, 
Elvis

Comment: I would suggest you post here the code you've already tried. And in case you haven't tried anything yet, please do.

Answer (score 1):

Edit /app/design/frontend///template/catalog/product/price.phtml
When you can't find, copy from base.

Around line 56:

```
<?php if (!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
```

change to:

```
<?php if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) : // look if logged in ?>
<?php if (!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
```

and at the end of the file

```
<?php endif; /* if (!$_product->isGrouped()): */ ?>
```

change to :

```
<?php endif; /* if (!$_product->isGrouped()): */ ?>        
<?php else: ?>
    <a href="/customer/account/login/">Login to view price</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Not tested

Comment: although I think it'll work, please try to test your code before presenting it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your last lines must be:

```
<?php else: ?>
    <a href="/customer/account/login/">Login to view price</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

After `<?php } ?>`

Comment: Thank you Henk. I implemented your code on the price.html file and did not see "Login to view price" when I was not logged in. Partial code below from price.phtml <?php if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) : // look if logged in ?> ente<?php if (!$_product->isGrouped()): ?> <?php $_weeeTaxAmount = $_weeeHelper->getAmountForDisplay($_product); ?> --------- <?php endif; /* if (!$_product->isGrouped()): */ ?> <?php else: ?> <a href="/customer/account/login/">Login to view price</a> <?php endif; ?> <?php } ?>

Comment: Thanks Henk. I tried this and my product page does not render normally. The Description, Reviews and right rail were removed. I see only the product image, title, and stock availability.

Comment: what is the URL?

Comment: Thank you Henk. The URL test product page is http://e.dev25.com/index.php/test1/test1.html

Comment: Why is there no pricebox in your theme?